# Android change textView after inflating another View

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater

Hi i'm trying to change a textview in an inflated view but the app crashes.

What i'm trying to do is fill the text views with the contents from the variables HomeTeam and AwayTeam these variables aren't null because when i log them the have names in there.

So my question is how do i change a text view and replace its contents

heres what I've tried

```
for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){

               resultsDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);
              String HomeTeam = resultsDict.getString("hometeam");
              String AwayTeam = resultsDict.getString("awayteam");

              Log.v("lc","hometeam" + HomeTeam);
              Log.v("lc","awayteam" + AwayTeam);


           }


           resultsView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.resultscell,
                     null);

           TextView homeTeam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
           homeTeam.setText(HomeTeam);
```

the inflated view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="-"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AwayScore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView04"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AwayTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AwayScore"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/AwayScore"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HomeTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

heres the error

```
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.uk.myApp.MyApp/co.uk.myApp.MyApp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at co.uk.myApp.MyApp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:576)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
05-18 13:55:57.552: E/AndroidRuntime(3987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change:

```
TextView homeTeam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
```

To this:

```
TextView homeTeam = (TextView) resultsView.findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
```

why? because *HomeTeam* is available in your inflated view. So, you need to refer to your inflated view/viewgroup when finding the child view

Comment: Thank you this was correct i will accept your answer later have to wait 10 minutes